# reference to a const player object

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
// Const in Classes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    std::string name;
   
    
public:
   
    std::string get_name() const  {         // consty method
        return name;
    }
    void set_name(std::string name_val) {
        name = name_val;
    }
    // Overloaded Constructors
    Player();
    Player(std::string name_val);
    Player(std::string name_val, int health_val, int xp_val);
};

Player::Player()
    : Player{ "None",0,0 } {
}

Player::Player(std::string name_val)
    : Player{ name_val,0, 0 } {
}

Player::Player(std::string name_val, int health_val, int xp_val)
    : name{ name_val }, health{ health_val }, xp{ xp_val } {
}

void display_player_name(const Player *p) {
    cout << p.get_name() << endl;
}

int main() {

    const Player villain{ "Villain", 100, 55 };

    Player niels{ "Niels", 100, 100 };
    Player albert{ niels };

    niels  = { "Margo", 100, 555 };

    cout << villain.get_name() << endl;
    display_player_name(niels);
    display_player_name(albert);  
   
    cout << villain.get_name() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And my question is about this piece of code:

```
void display_player_name(const Player *p) {
    cout << p.get_name() << endl;
}
```

So this is a ref to a const player object. But what is the purpose of doing this?

Because if I do it like this. This will not compile anyway:

```
void display_player_name(const Player p) {
    cout << p.get_name() << endl;
}
```

It will return the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const Player *p` is a **pointer** to `const`-`Player`. It's not a reference at all. (And you code doesn't compile at least because of that).

If you want a reference you need `void display_player_name(const Player& p)`.

In `void display_player_name(const Player p)` `Player` is passed by value, so it will be copied before being used by the function.

The main difference between the two in this case is that the value is copied in one case and not in the other.

It outputs the same, because you're not changing the data, but passing a pointer or a reference will be more efficient, because you don't have to duplicate your object, which can be expensive (especially if done multiple times). And there's no real reason to make a copy here.